# Gitlab docker ci template - what is the header name for

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

At first example, the image name is `docker:latest`.
And the stage is the defination of pipeline that i can have build,  test, deploy stages.

#### Snippet 1

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
docker-build:
    # Use the official docker image.
    image: docker:latest
    stage: build
```

- May i know the defination of `docker-build`?
- Can i named it `build` or something else, what is the usage?

#### Snippet 2

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t test .
```

- In another example, there is services defined. Why i need services and when i don't need it?
- Can i say this example must have another file 'Dockerfile' so the docker build command only works?
- Once build successfully , the image will be named docker:latest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Job-naming:

There are a few reserved keywords which you can not use for a job name, like `stages`, `services` etc. see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#unavailable-names-for-jobs

you can name your job anything else you like.

#### Stages

As you have written there are a certain set of pre defined stages: `.pre`, `build`, `test`, `deploy` and `.post` - but you can also define your own stages with

```
stages:
  - build
  - build-docker
  - test
  - deploy
```

### Dockerfile

yes you need a dockerfile to docker build, and the tag of your image will be `test` as it is defined with `-t test`.
Regarding building docker images with gitlab ci i can recommen https://blog.callr.tech/building-docker-images-with-gitlab-ci-best-practices/ to read.

I hope this helps somehow. Generally speaking i recommend you to read the gitlab documentation and the getting started guide: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/ - it explains a lot of the default concepts. and i would recommend to not ask to many questions within in one stackoverflow question, keep it focused to one topic

Comment: Thanks! In my case, my gitlab is airgapped no internet connection. I stored docker images at nexus repo. For the pull case, does it means the docker up and run after pull or i have to input the docker command at gitlab yml 'script'?

Comment: At script,  after pull image, am i need to input docker run command to up the docker container?